# Networkx weights on edges with cumulative sum

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am drawing a networkx graph with weights on edges, which I want to sum weight cumulatively. The code below only gets the last weight of edges but the cumulative sum. There are 5 nodes and 3 edges. The edges are `('A', 'B'), ('A', 'D')`, and `('C', 'E')`, and the weight is `[1, 1, 1]`. What I want the weight is `[2, 2, 1]` not `[1, 1, 1]`. Need help. Tks.

**1. Create a df**

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
ints = [1] * 5
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A']
b = ['D', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'B']
df = pd.DataFrame(ints, columns=['weight'])
df['a'] = a
df['b'] = b
df

    weight  a   b
0   1       A   D
1   1       B   A
2   1       C   E
3   1       A   D
4   1       A   B
```

**2. Draw a graph**.

```
G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'a', 'b', ['weight'])
edges = G.edges() 
weights = [G[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True,  width=weights)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I don't think you can do a cumulative sum directly with `nx.from_pandas_dataframe`, at least after a quick look to the documentation.

You can, however, do that in `pandas` before passing it to `networkx`.

Since you said that you want weights to be `[2,2,1]`, it means you're considering the graph as undirected, so you'll have to ensure that first:

```
df["a'"] = pd.DataFrame([df["a"], df["b"]]).min()
df["b'"] = pd.DataFrame([df["a"], df["b"]]).max()
```

Then you can do the cumulative sum with a simple `groupby`:

```
df = df.groupby(by = ["a'", "b'"]).sum().reset_index()
```

At this point, `df` will be correctly converted by `nx.from_pandas_dataframe`:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, "a'", "b'", ['weight'])
[G[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]
```

Comment: In networkx 2.0 `nx.from_pandas_dataframe` has been removed. Therefore, use  `G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, "a'", "b'", ['weight'])` and `[G[u][v]['weight'] for u, v in G.edges()]` instead. I hope it works.